# Form that will store offline

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, offline

I've been doing a fair amount of research on this, and can't find a solution that quite fits my needs.  I'm trying to find a way to have a simple html form (an email sign-up sheet) that will store the data offline, possibly with html5 localStorage.  I've been looking at this solution: http://miniapps.co.uk/blog/post/using-html5-localstorage-as-a-fallback-for-offline-form-submission, but I'm not sure how to make this work as a stand-alone html doc that isn't stored on an online server.  Any suggestions?

Comment: HTML5 local storage is on the clients browser, much like the SESSION is stored on the serve.  And most of the time it does not survive a browser restart.  Local storage is also isolated from access by other sites.  Is this what you want?  Where exactly do you want to store this data?

Comment: @Vigrond no, this is not what I want at all.  Ideally, I'd like to store the data in an excel file.  I know that you can do all of this within excel, but I want the form to be very basic, very simple, and secure.

Comment: Ok, where do you want the excel file to be?  You mention 'offline', but do you mean your local computer instead of your rented server?

Comment: @Vigrond I think what you say is true of the `sessionStorage`, but the  `localStorage` object is supposed to be more permanent, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/. Either way, I think access to either object requires the request come from a url, so I don't think this is the way to go.

Comment: @nwellcome  you are right, thanks for the correction.  HTML5 LocalStorage will survive just like browser cache, until cleared.

Comment: @Vigrond yes, local computer.  Ideally, it would all be processed and stored on the local machine.

Comment: @nwellcome, yes, that's what I understand as well.  I need to be able to pull up the form locally, without a connection, if need be.

Comment: @blackessej just to clarify once more before I post a solution... you want the client to fill out your form, have it put into an excel file, and have it saved on YOUR (not the clients) local computer?  (like the one you're using now)

Comment: @Vigrond - Yes, yes, yes.  And thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not going to post a bunch of code for you, but I will give you a solution.

The **first problem** is having a remote server save a file on your own local computer.  This can be solved by setting up an FTP server (which will require an online connection), creating an FTP client account, and accessing it using whatever server back-end language you're using (PHP, C#, etc.)

I like FileZilla server: http://filezilla-project.org/

In the cases when your local computer is offline, you can set your server to save the information to a database, and 'retry' connecting to your computer's ftp server until it's successful.  This can be done using CRON jobs in a linux environment.  The steps involved would be like:

1. Check the database for any new form data
2. If there is, try connecting to FTP server and saving
3. If successful, mark database status column in the row as 'success'.

In the cases where your IP address changes, you can sign up for a free dynamic dns account that will give you a permenant address.  Here's a popular one: http://dyn.com/dns/

The **second problem** is getting this form data into an Excel file.  Thankfully, there have been open-source libraries created for this purpose such as [PHP-Excel](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/) that will convert a database table or a php 2-dimensional array into an excel file.

When your user completes the form, it can create this excel file, put it in a directory, and save the path into the database where your CRON job or Windows Task Scheduler will execute a script to save that file on your local computer via FTP.

Comment: much thanks, but I think this is a bit overkill for me.  There is really no need to get online, ever.  It would just be an offline laptop who's soul purpose would be to collect emails from people who type them in.  Pretty much just like a physical pen and paper email sign up sheet.  I would like an approach that just addresses the second problem, so the PHP-Excel solution that you suggest seems like a good candidate.  I can set up a PHP file locally on the laptop and have it convert an array into an excel file.  Thanks!

Comment: sorry didn't realize the actual server would be offline! :)

Comment: That's alright!  It's not an ideal situation or problem, but a solution must be found nonetheless.  Thanks again.